# AutoLisp DCL - Popup_List Icon - Adding the Icon

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I am wanting to add an icon to a popup list tile in a Dialog Control Language (DCL) file to use in an AutoLisp script. From AutoDesk's website, [link here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARXMAC/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-EE92EC2B-83BB-4EFE-907A-F413836D78EE), the example image shows this as being possible. From the information it has provided, I have gathered that part of a string needs to be added to the `list` attribute. This leaves me with one final question, how do I link an icon with a popup list tile?

[image: Icons within the popup list tile.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is not possible using standard DCL (and the developer documentation is therefore misrepresentative). You would need to use [OpenDCL](https://opendcl.com/wordpress/) to achieve this functionality.