# AutoLisp - Finding a Specific Icon

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I'm wanting to find a specific icon in my cad software that I wish to use elsewhere. How do I find the icon shown in the image below? This is a default text style font icon. I will be using this icon in a DCL popup list, which is further described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176571/autolisp-dcl-popup-list-icon-adding-the-icon).

[image: Default Text Style Font Icon]